# How to manage battery and AC on Lenovo

Tags: power-management, lenovo

I own a [Lenovo Z410][1] laptop, and its battery is not removable.  Lenovo published an ['energy management' driver for Windows][2] that let you to use ac power instead of battery when the battery power is between 55% and 60%. How may I do this in Ubuntu?

I notic that if i turn on this option in windows and restart to ubuntu whitout unpluging charger, battery doesn't charging and device use ac power.

[1]: cpu: core i7 4702MQ

[2]: you're right. It's a driver. But when you install it, an app named "power manager" appear in app menu.

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-z-series-laptops/ideapad-z410-notebook shows no drivers for Linux at all.

Comment: It may be useful to know which version of the Z410 you have as http://notebookplanet.blogspot.com/2013/11/lenovo-ideapad-z410-specs.html shows there are at least six CPUs (i7-4700MQ, i5-4200M, i3-4100M, i3-4000M, Pentium 3550M and Celeron 2950M) and therefore there will be hundreds of configurations. Would you please be so kind as to provide us with the model number from the serial number plate underneath? To do so, please click on the _edit_ link above on the left, and update your question with this detail.

Comment: It's not not duplicate. That metod is for thinkpads and dont work for ideapads.

Comment: The other question isn't specific to any device. If none of the posted solutions over there work for you then the answer is that that there is currently no solution available for your device.